# BootstrapTable - Extension - FixedColumn [not working]

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-table

i am using https://bootstrap-table.com with the extension **bootstrap-table-fixed-columns**, but i don't get it to work properly. The problem is that, the first column should be fixed, but it isn't. Example : https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#extensions/fixed-columns.html

after i load the modal there should be 2 columns fixed

```
  $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
  $table.bootstrapTable({ fixedColumns: true, fixedFrom: 'left', fixedNumber: 2 });
```

minimal code example

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Hello, Bootstrap Table!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTable">
  Launch modal table
</button>
<div id="modalTable" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal table</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="table1"
          data-toggle="table"
          data-height="500">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th >ID</th>
              <th >Item Name</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>
              <th >Item Price</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js"></script>
  </body>

  <script>
  var $table = $('#table1')

  $(function() {
    $('#modalTable').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
      $table.bootstrapTable({ fixedColumns: true, fixedFrom: 'left', fixedNumber: 2 });
    })
  })
</script>
</html>
```

best regards
Howell